# SwiftUI: How could I use polymorphism to make a model class create its own View

Tags: swift, swiftui, polymorphism, observableobject

I am trying to build a small App in which you can create tests with questions using SwifUI, but finding how to make everything works out is getting hard for a newbie like me. The app would show a list of questions in a main scrollable view and these questions could be of different types such as true or false, text, multiple choice, etc… and could be active or not.

I thought it would be great that all different types of questions adopted the same protocol. This protocol would also define a function or a computed property in charge of display its on view using the values store in the different attributes. However, **the problem comes up when trying to modify any of this parameters interacting with that View**. Let's say I want to add a toggle button that active or reactive the question, modifying one of the values of that question. With the different solutions I implemented, I didn't get the view being rebuild/updated.

I tried several things to accomplish this, like wrapping those properties that are supposed to update their values with @State or @Binding. I also tried to turn those properties into ObservableObjects, adding new classes that adopt the ObservableObject protocol, but it does not work. The only thing that seems to work is, for any type of Question, create a view, with an observable ViewModel. Later, in the view where I display all the question, I have to create a Switch with all the different possibilities.

What I don't like about this solutions is that if I wanted to add a new type of question, I would have to modify this main view to include an extra case for this new type of question, what is against the Open-Closed principle.

Do you have any suggestion guys to assign this responsibility to any question class instead of to the main view?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: A view gets updated when any of it's dependencies gets changed example: `@State`, `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject`, `@EnvironmentObject`. I suggest you please watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040

Comment: There is no way of getting around SwiftUI wrappers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments guys :). I know what you mean @user1046037, actually I make it work when I implement it using a MVVM pattern, so the view is controlled by its view model, which adopts the observableObject protocol. However, from the point of view of extending the App, making a model display its own interacting view by adopting a custom protocol could be a cleaner solution. In case I wanted to add a new type of question, I would have to create that new model, adopting that protocol and defining the way the view would be displayed without touching or affecting anything else.

Comment: IMHO try to keep it simple and maintainable rather than complicating it for what might come in the future. I feel it is better to let the app and framework take its form  rather than coercing it to follow a particular architecture. It is better not to fight the system

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't want a model to know about the view. That's backwards. But yet we often want to hide the concrete selection logic behind a single call that does different things depending on the data provided (similar to polymorphism via function overloading).

The key idea is the use of the [Factory Pattern](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-26) combined with the [Visitor Pattern](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-30) to keep in harmony with the Open-Closed Principle.

When we do this kind of thing with regular objects, we often use a factory method to return the proper subclass for the input data. [Inside that factory method usually sits a `switch` statement.](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2021/03/06/ifElseSwitch.html) The factory interface lets us honor the Open-Closed principle so that `ContentView` doesn't change when we add new question types. Chances are, what follows is probably very similar to what you had yourself with the view model approach.

In SwiftUI, the best approach at a factory-style view would be to create a `QuestionView` that then knows how to create the correct concrete view for each question object. I hope that `default` + `fatalError()` makes you consider how an `enum` might be useful here.

```swift
struct QuestionView: View {
    let question: Question
    
    var body: some View {
        switch question {
        case let q as TextQuestion:
            TextQuestionView(question: q)
        case let q as DoubleQuestion:
            DoubleQuestionView(question: q)
        default:
            fatalError("Unknown question type")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main view it would be polymorphic, reacting dynamically to the actual `Question` instances. You'd use it something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private(set) var questions: [Question]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(questions, id: \.key) { question in
                    QuestionView(question: question)
                }
                
                Button("Submit") {
                    let answers = Answers()
                    for question in questions {
                        question.record(answers: answers)
                    }
                    print(answers)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Questions")
        }
    }
}
```

A reasonable way to extract the answers is to use the Visitor Pattern in a way similar in structure to `Encodable`'s `encode(to encoder: Encoder)`. We expect each specialty view to communicate with its specific `Question` object, and then expect the `Question` object to contain an implementation of `func record(answers: Answers)`. When it's time, loop through `questions` and tell them to record their answers. (Note that we can add various `Answers` implementations without changing the `Question` subclasses, in keeping with the Open-Closed principle).

The `Question` objects are like view models, and they are `ObservableObjects`. You can see how they record their answers when asked.

For this to work, they cannot be protocols with associated types. That just kills using them in an array.

```swift
class TextQuestion: Question, ObservableObject {
    @Published var answer = ""
    
    override func record(answers: Answers) {
        answers.addAnswer(key: key, value: answer)
    }
}

class MeasurementQuestion: Question, ObservableObject {
    let unit: String
    @Published var answer = 0.0
    
    init(key: String, question: String, unit: String) {
        self.unit = unit
        super.init(key: key, question: question)
    }
    
    override func record(answers: Answers) {
        answers.addAnswer(key: key, value: answer)
    }
}
```

Then each individual question subtype view will watch its own `Question` instance:

```
struct TextQuestionView: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var question: TextQuestion
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(question.question) {
            TextField("Answer", text: $question.answer)
        }
    }
}

struct MeasurementQuestionView: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var question: MeasurementQuestion
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(question.question) {
            HStack {
                TextField("Answer", value: $question.answer, format: .number)
                Text(question.unit)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can simply add your [list of questions](https://www.bookofthrees.com/monty-python-and-the-holy-grail-bridge-three-questions/) to the preview and see how it works:

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(questions: Example.questions)
    }
}

struct Example {
    static let questions: [Question] = [
        TextQuestion(
            key: "name",
            question: "What...is your name?"
        ),
        TextQuestion(
            key: "quest",
            question: "What...is your quest?"
        ),
        [
            TextQuestion(
                key: "assyria",
                question: "What...is the capital of Assyria?"
            ),
            TextQuestion(
                key: "color",
                question: "What...is your favorite colour?"
            ),
            MeasurementQuestion(
                key: "swallow",
                question: "What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
                unit: "kph"
            )
        ].randomElement()!
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure I *like* this implementation for anything beyond a toy project—I prefer stronger layer separations. This does, however, setup a polymorphic view that adjusts to data implementation types. The key idea is the use of the [Factory Pattern](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-26) combined with the [Visitor Pattern](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-30).

Comment: How could we make the question view polymorphic itself without relying on the switch ?